# Up sampling the moving min of ARIMA process

Tags: time-series, sampling

Say, I have a ARIMA(P,D,Q) process $x_t$, at the original frequency. This is unobservable.

However, I observe the nonoverlapping periodic minimum of these series $m_q$, where for given period length $n$
$$m_q\equiv\min \{x_{qn},...,x_{(q+1)n-1}\}$$

I want to up sample to obtain more frequent series $m_d$ such that:
$$m_d\equiv\min \{x_{dn/k},...,x_{(d+1)n/k-1}\},$$
where $k$ is a factor. I want to convert $m_q$ to $m_d$.

For instance, I have the series of monthly minimum daily rainfall. Now I want to convert this series to weekly minimum of the rainfall. Daily rainfall is unobservable.

Any ideas?

ARMA is also helpful if it's easier to deal with stationary series.

Comment: Do we know anything about the distribution of error term $\epsilon_t$?

Comment: You can assume nice properties. E.g. iid normal

Comment: Just to clarify, the subscripts in $m_q$ and $m_d$ have nothing to do with the q and d in the ARIMA(p,d,q) specification, right?

Comment: Also, to clarify, your example of monthly and weekly is correct? You're not looking at, for instance, recovering weekly minima from a (daily or weekly) sliding 4-week period, but rather the larger periods do not overlap and the smaller periods are contained completely within them and also do not overlap. Right?

Comment: @Wayne correct on both comments